# Class 'HttpResponse' not found

Tags: php, http

According to PHP documentation, HttpResponse is a static class to manipulate the Http response to the requester.

The code `echo HttpResponse::getBufferSize();`

throws the error in the Subject of this post.

Any ideas?  Maybe it's some config, but I am a PHP newbie and I'm not sure where to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/http.install.php):

> This PECL extension is not bundled
>   with PHP.

You need to install it via PECL http://pecl.php.net/package/pecl_http. To see how to install PECL, see (again) the [docs](http://php.net/manual/de/install.pecl.php).

If you haven't heard of PECL, read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Extension_Community_Library#PECL) page!