# Unable to redirect using header(Location:)

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am unable to redirect from the login page of my site to the dashboard. When I try to login by giving the correct username and password it again shows me the login page, but when I access the dashboard of my site by url I can access it which proves that session has started.
Below is my code:

```
<?php

      error_reporting(0);
      session_start();
      include_once '../db.php';

      if(isset($_REQUEST['admsubmit']))
      {

          $result=executeQuery("select * from adminlogin where admname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'],ENT_QUOTES)."' and admpassword='".md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES))."'");

         // $result=mysql_query("select * from adminlogin where admname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'])."' and admpassword='".md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password']))."'");
          if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
          {

              $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
              if(strcmp($r['admpassword'],md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)))==0)
              {
                  $_SESSION['admname']=htmlspecialchars_decode($r['admname'],ENT_QUOTES);
                  unset($_GLOBALS['message']);
                  header('Location: admwelcome.php');
              }else
          {
             $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";

          }

          }
          else
          {
              $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";

          }
          closedb();
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you have any errors popping up? Do you have error reporting turned on? Can you show us the contents of `db.php`?

Comment: You have error_reporting turned off. Turn it on and ass the error message to your OP.

Comment: You should put an `exit;` behind `header()` anyway.

Comment: I tried putting exit; that also didnt work

Comment: I told you it was the output buffer :-). I'm glad I was of assistance. I added the activating output buffer via htaccess step to my solution so future users will have a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with PHP, the problem is you cannot redirect a user after the page buffer has been emptied. The problem is you must send the headers before anything else for them to be recognized. You script sends html data before sending the Location header that causes the user to redirect, that's why redirecting does not work.

To resolve this issue you must start the buffer at the first line of PHP code to prevent html data being sent, and empty it (if the buffer gets full, it will empty automatically) at the end of the file. You can also specify the buffer size in the config file.

To turn on output_buffering add the following line to your .htaccess file

```
php_flag output_buffering on
```

To start the buffer you use the **ob_start()** function (http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ob-start.php).

To empty the buffer in case it has not filled, you use the **ob_end_flush()** function (http://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ob-end-flush.php).

Your code should be:

```
<?php

  ob_start(); // start the page buffer so html data is not sent before the header

  error_reporting(0);
  session_start();
  include_once '../db.php';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['admsubmit']))
  {

      $result=executeQuery("select * from adminlogin where admname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'],ENT_QUOTES)."' and admpassword='".md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES))."'");

     // $result=mysql_query("select * from adminlogin where admname='".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['name'])."' and admpassword='".md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password']))."'");
      if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
      {

          $r=mysql_fetch_array($result);
          if(strcmp($r['admpassword'],md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)))==0)
          {
              $_SESSION['admname']=htmlspecialchars_decode($r['admname'],ENT_QUOTES);
              unset($_GLOBALS['message']);
              header('Location: admwelcome.php');
          }else
      {
         $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";

      }

      }
      else
      {
          $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";

      }
      closedb();
  }

  ob_end_flush(); // empty the buffer and send the html code back to the browser

  ?>
```

I also use a redirect function so I can redirect more easily:

```
function redirect($to) {

   header("Location: " . $to);

}
```

Now you can redirect like this (it seems far more easier to the eye):

```
redirect("admwelcome.php");
```

Please rate my answer as I am a new user and can't rate others just yet :-)

Comment: This too didn't work, whats happening I can't understand, redirecting was never too tough.

Comment: I think you need to set the correct buffer size. This is surely the problem. I haven't done any php coding in some time, but I'm searching for an answer :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to change the buffer size

Comment: Do you use WAMP or XAMP? you need to access the php.ini file. Do you have access to it?

Comment: No I am using a hosting site, but i can't find php.ini there

Comment: Try adding <?php echo HttpResponse::getBufferSize(); die(); ?> or <?php echo BufferSize(); die(); ?> ON THE FIRST LINE OF YOUR FILE and please tell me the output showed

Comment: it says "Fatal error: Class 'HttpResponse' not found"

&

Fatal error: Call to undefined function BufferSize()

Comment: So it seems this is a dead end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175524/class-httpresponse-not-found ... I am searching for a new answer now

Comment: If you have access to the cPanel, you should find a way to edit the php.ini file (could be in configurations). If you find the php.ini file and can edit it, search for "output_buffering" and set it to a value. let's say output_buffering=10240

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 2 minutes ago... Now is solved :)

Try using JavaScript. Remplace header location, in the php code

```
?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 


   window.location ="http://www.sirobd.com/index.php";

</script>
<?php
```

Comment: This is not an ideal solution at all, since it requires the cooperation of the user agent (which might even not expose JavaScript support at all).

Comment: yes I was facing many other issues after doing it, I turned on ouput buffering by editing .htaccess file and now it works properly.

Comment: I know is not really perfect, but its all i have haha ob_star is not working. With me works good

Answer (score 0):

try this code with meta. in content attribut, you can change the number, it's the time in second before the redirection

```
    if(strcmp($r['admpassword'],md5(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES)))==0){
        $_SESSION['admname']=htmlspecialchars_decode($r['admname'],ENT_QUOTES);
        unset($_GLOBALS['message']);
        echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2;url=http://yourWebsite/admwelcome.php">';              
    }else{
         $_GLOBALS['message']="Check Your user name and Password.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
session_write_close();
```

before the header call, and then add exit for good measure.

```
session_write_close();
header('Location: admwelcome.php');
exit;
```

Comment: Its not working, just tried and I just see a blank page with the same login page url.